# Simplify/reuse subqueries in this SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE (
  users.id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM managerships WHERE managerships.employee_id = 1234) OR
  users.custom_id IN (SELECT manager_custom_id FROM managerships WHERE managerships.employee_id = 1234) OR
  users.saml_id IN (SELECT manager_saml_id FROM managerships WHERE managerships.employee_id = 1234) OR
  users.email IN (SELECT manager_email FROM managerships WHERE managerships.employee_id = 1234)
)
```

Now I believe there should be a way to just select once from my `managerships` table and reuse it, something like:

```
SELECT manager_id, manager_email, manager_custom_id, manager_saml_id FROM managerships WHERE managerships.employee_id = 1234
```

How can I achieve that? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try just joining the `users` and `managerships` tables together:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM "users" t1
INNER JOIN managerships t2
    ON t1.id        = t2.manager_id OR
       t1.custom_id = t2.manager_custom_id OR
       t1.saml_id   = t2.manager_saml_id OR
       t1.email     = t2.manager_email
WHERE t2.employee_id = 1234;
```

This approach, in addition to being easier to read, has the added of advantage of possibly being able to use indices on the two tables, assuming you have defined them.

Comment: Thank you, Tim! I went with your approach and it works great. I just had to `GROUP` the results to get unique entries.

Answer (score 14):

You can use WITH to take the aggregations out into a CTE (common table expression):

```
WITH m AS (SELECT manager_id
                 ,manager_email
                 ,manager_custom_id
                 ,manager_saml_id 
           FROM   managerships 
           WHERE  managerships.employee_id = 1234
)
SELECT "users".* FROM "users"
WHERE (
  users.id IN (SELECT manager_id FROM m) OR
  users.custom_id IN (SELECT manager_custom_id FROM m) OR
  users.saml_id IN (SELECT manager_saml_id FROM m) OR
  users.email IN (SELECT manager_email FROM m)
);
```

Pls refer also https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html

Comment: What if multiple statements need to use m?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the query as something like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     managerships m
WHERE m.employee_id = 1234 AND
      (u.id = m.manager_id OR
       u.custom_id = m.manager_custom_id OR
       u.saml_id = m.manager_saml_id OR
       u.email = m.manager_email 
      );
```

I don't think there is any improvement on performance.  Any version of this query really needs an index on `managerships(employee_id)`.  With this index, your query and this should have pretty much the same performance.

Note:  You can express this using `on` -- it does the same thing.  Because of the `OR` the conditions cannot really be optimized, which is why I'm putting them in the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you, Gordon!