# Using the same SELECT statement in two different DELETE statements

Tags: postgresql

How can I factor out the common SELECT statement in the following function?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE delete_comment(cid integer[]) AS $$
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM comment_tree_path
    WHERE descendant IN (SELECT descendant 
                         FROM comment_tree_path 
                         WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid));
    DELETE FROM comment 
    WHERE comment_id IN (SELECT descendant 
                         FROM comment_tree_path 
                         WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid));
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Actually the second DELETE statement won't work, because the first one will delete all rows with `cids` from `comment_tree_path` table and as a result the second SELECT will be empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Simplify/reuse subqueries in this SQL query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43197110/simplify-reuse-subqueries-in-this-sql-query)

Comment: A simple work-around would be to swap the order of the deletes so the table isn't cleared when trying to delete from `comment`

Comment: Why not just use a `FOREIGN KEY` from `comment` to `comment_tree_path` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`?

Comment: @nofinator AFAIK you cannot use two queries that end with a semicolon after `WITH`.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I don't think it is possible. `comment_tree_path` is a closure table with columns `ancestor`, `descendant` and `path_length`. If a comment has children, they should be deleted too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CTE:

```
with descendants as (
  SELECT descendant 
  FROM comment_tree_path 
  WHERE ancestor = ANY(cid)
), delete_tree_path as (
  DELETE FROM comment_tree_path
  WHERE descendant IN (select descendant from descendants)
)
DELETE FROM comment 
WHERE comment_id IN (select descendant from descendants);
```

Comment: Could you please see this [answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/320089/260780) and let me know if it is better than your solution or not?

Comment: Why do you not run both answers and see which runs better in your system.